# Arcpy field calculation with user selected field

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-script-tool

I could really use some help with an arcpy field calculation.I need to concatenate a float and a string to populate a TEXT field with distances and units to feed to the buffer function. I will need to buffer multiple points at various distances but with a single unit of measure.
I am reading in the field name from the script tool, and I'm allowing the user to select a units string from a value list so I do not know what the actual field name or unit string will be.

```
Dist_Field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
    # In my test data this field is called "Dist" 
    # and is sourced to an input table in the script tool
Units = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) 
    # selection from a value list of valid unit strings - 
    # METERS, MILES etc...

# What goes in the expression argument?
arcpy.CalculateField_management (CopiedTable, "DistUnits", ? ,"PYTHON") 
    # DistUnits is a TEXT field that I created so I know its field name

    # I attempted to use the following as the expression
      # "'str(Dist_Field)+" Kilometers"'"
      # I don't have the actual line of code handy, but variations on this 
      # return the field name + Kilometers:  ( Dist Kilometers )
      # I've also tried "'str(Dist_Field) + str (Units)'"
    # a literal field name string or units string is no use to me as I only 
      # know the variable name
```

How do I concatenate a float field with a string variable and write it to the new TEXT field when I only know variable names?

I'm flailing in my attempts figure out how this works.

This is my first attempt at both Python and ArcPy.

Comment: I removed the second question because there should always be only one, but there appears to be no role for cursors here anyway.

Comment: Convert to m and supply it as parameter to tool

Comment: What happens when you run your code?  Often an error message will point you where you need to look.

Comment: I reviewed the linked answer prior to posting this question. My question differs in that I do not know what the actual value of either component will be. The crux of my question is can I modify all of the records in the field at once, only knowing a string that matches the name of the field, or will I need to loop through individual values?          I don't understand the convert to m suggestion, please clarify.